# Building Server-client application with CakePHP and Android

Tags: php, android, cakephp, authentication, plugins

I'm currently building an application on Android that allows user to register a location-based service. I'm pretty new in both server-side programming and Android. Therefore I need some suggestions to point me to the right direction.

Concretely, my Android application will allow users to register, login, and update their profile and settings on the server side, and I'm using Apache as my server.

My idea now is using CakePHP on the server-side, and use JSON/XML format to communicate with the Android App via HTTP POST and response. I don't want to rebuild everything like authentication from scratch, however I can't find any CakePHP plugin that work for me. I've tried CakeDC and Authake. CakeDC seems incompatible with current CakePHP version. For Authake, I've followed the steps on the Authake Tutorial, however, the register and login page do not work. (I can't use admin to login as well.)

**Summary**
1. Is this server-client architecture feasible?
2. Can anyone point me to an CakePHP authentication/registration plugin which is compatible with current CakePHP?

Answer (score 0):

1. Seems feasible to me. Though you might have to build a REST or
   similar interface if you are letting users log in remotely through
   the web interface.
2. I used the [User Management plugin](https://github.com/chetanvarshney/User-Management-Plugin-for-Cakephp-2.x) for my auth-based CakePHP programs and really like it.